# Can .html files sent as attachments be opened and run on iPhone5 (OS9.2)

Tags: mail.app, email, iphone, html

I write a simple front-end web page. Fully self-contained in the usual CSS3/JS/HTML5 format.  It works in XCode simulation. I e-mail it as an attachment to a (long suffering) relative with an iPhone5 (OS9.2). He cannot get it to run, or even open properly. Same story when we try the transfer via DropBox. Some files I've sent appear to open but stall at the first touchevent:  Mail intercepts the touchevent and concludes we are DONE.

We are both newbies. Are we missing something obvious? Is there a (legal) workaround this problem? Any advice or pointers will be enthusiastically received. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, iOS devices do not support offline website or HTML viewing.

As an alternative, you could get your relative to purchase [GoodReader from the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/goodreader/id777310222?mt=8) and have him open the file in that app, or use an FTP website-hosting service such as [000webhost](http://www.000webhost.com).

Answer (score 1):

In the end, we realized that any file in DropBox (Public) gets a web address. This seems to be working for us.